# How do I call a second UserForm

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I'm new to VBA and I'm developing a macro in Word VBA. I have 2 buttons in a word sheet to do 2 different things. Each buttons needs to open  different userForms.

When I developed the first button, I'm calling the first userForm by doing this:

```vb
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call DisplayUserForm
End Sub
```

Now, for my second button, where i have a CommandButton2_Click(), how do I assign the userForm2 to my second button?

So the logic here is:

- I have 1 sheet with 2 seperate buttons to do different things;
- 1 UserForm does one thing, the userForm2 does other things;
- The both UserForms are never connected.

I've tried to call the UserForm2 in many different ways and searched on how to do it, but with no sucess. All i can find is calling a userform inside of another userform, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

When you double-click, in design mode, a `CommandButton` control, a click handler skeleton is created for you to fill in with code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.Show 'type this yourself
    ...
End Sub
```

For the second button you do the same - create the button - double-click it and voila:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    UserForm2.Show 'type this yourself
    ...
End Sub
```